# Passing data relation to view laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I finish to make relation in my model, but i dont know to passing data relation to view, hope you can help me.

> Model Siswa

```
 public function Absen()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Absen::class);
}
```

> Model Absen

```
public function Siswa()
{
    $this->belongsTo(Siswa::class);
}
```

[image: Absen tabel]

Absen Table

[image: Siswa Table]

Siswa Table

> AbsenController@index

```
public function index()
{

    $absen = Absen::where('level', '=', 'Siswa')->get();

    return view('absen.index')->with('data', $absen);
}
```

> index.blade.php

```
@foreach($data as $index => $value)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->nama }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->keterangan }}</td>
              <td>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['siswa.destroy', $value->id], 
               'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                  {{ Form::submit('Hapus', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
                  <a href="{{ route('siswa.edit', $value->id) }}" class="btn 
                btn-warning">Edit</a>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

The problem is the $value->nama not showing in my view, but i done to create relation in table siswa and table absen.Thank

Comment: I think there's some confusion here. What data are you actually trying to display in your view? You're trying to access `$value->nama`, but that column doesn't exist on the `Absen` model??

Comment: $value->nama its refers to Table Siswa @fubar

Comment: I understand that. But in your controller, you're querying table Absen, not table Siswa, which is why the attribute is empty. So that's your mistake.

Comment: @fubar how can i do in my controller?

Comment: Can you update with your question with what you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nama is not an attribute of Absen class, yet your value is an Absen class. Though you have defined the relationship between Absen and Siswa, attributes of Siswa are still not directly inherited to Absens. You can first get the Siswa of the Absen and then get the attributes of the Siswa.

So what you have to do is:

Call `$value->Siswa->nama` instead of `$value->nama`, and you should have your nama displayed.